# Sitecore How to add Item's version in English language via pipelines

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7.2

Using the Sitecore event handler 'OnItemSave', I am adding an English language verison of the item if it does not exist.

```
public void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var item = Event.ExtractParameter<Item>(args, 0);
    if (item == null) return;
    //Add version of item in English
    if (Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(item.ID, Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager.GetLanguage("en")) == null)
    using (new LanguageSwitcher("en"))
       {
         item.Versions.AddVersion(); 
       }
}
```

But this does not add the version in the `en` language, it adds it in the `Content Language`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I remember, when you call:

```cs
Item enItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(item.ID, Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager.GetLanguage("en"))
```

and if there no `en` version but this item has version in ANY other language, you will still get an Item object but `enItem.Versions.Count` will be 0.

You should try something like that (not tested!):

```
Item enItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(item.ID, Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager.GetLanguage("en"))
if (enItem.Versions.Count == 0)
{
    using (new LanguageSwitcher("en"))
    {
        enItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
        enItem.Versions.AddVersion();
        enItem.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**
If you need to copy fields from the original item to EN item:

1. `Item newEnVersion = enItem.Versions.AddVersion();`
2. `item.Fields.ReadAll()`
3. `foreach (Field field in _item.Fields) { if (field != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_item[field.Key]))  { newEnItem[field.Key] = _item[field.Key] } }`

Comment: Thanks, What I need to do if I also want to keep the same data in `English` Version. any Idea other than marking the fields as 'Shared' ?